# Print enum as a string

Tags: c++, c

I have actually an enum in c++:

```
class myClass
{
public:
    enum ExampleType
    {
       TEST1
       TEST2
       TEST3
       TEST4
    }
};
```

I would like to print the enum not as number but as String..
Actually it prints *0 .. 1 .. 2 .. 3*
I would like it print **TEST1** or **TEST2** etc ...

I already try Switch case as :

```
 std::string type;
  switch (this->type)
    {
    case 0:   type = "TEST1";
    case 1:   type = "TEST2";
    case 2: type = "TEST3";
    case 3: type = "TEST4";
    }
```

then print type, but he don't go in the right case ..

How can it be possible ?

Comment: Add a `break;` after each assignment in the `case`.

Comment: Thx Gene, my bad, first time i use switch case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C/C++, `case` statements fall through. You must use `break` to exit the switch statement. If your `this->type` is 0, then the code that is executed is:

```
type = "TEST1";
type = "TEST2";
type = "TEST3";
type = "TEST4";
```

What you want is:

```
switch( this->type )
{
case TEST1: type = "TEST1";
            break;
case TEST2: type = "TEST2";
            break;
//...
}
```

Or, if you have a function that is returning this value, simply return the value:

```
std::string type_string()
{
    switch( this->type )
    {
    case TEST1: return "TEST1";
    case TEST2: return "TEST2";
    //...
    default:    return std::string::empty();
    }
}
```

Note: (Since @DoxyLover's comment) I changed the switch to use the declared enum constants as you should use these instead. If someone added a `TEST0` to the start of the enum, then the switch statement will still execute correctly, while your version would not.

Comment: In addition, use the enum values for the cases: `case TEST1:` instead of `case 0:`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, you can also do something like this:  (C99)

```
#include <ansi_c.h>

enum ExampleType
{
    TEST1,
    TEST2,
    TEST3,
    TEST4,
    TEST_MAX
};

const char string[TEST_MAX][10]={"TEST1","TEST2","TEST3","TEST4"};


int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<TEST_MAX;i++)
    {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, string[i]);   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hell Yeah, worked too, there is so many possibilities !

Comment: Most of the time there is more than one way to skin a cat. (or something less gruesome if you prefer)

Answer (score 1):

In switch-case statements, evaluation falls through between the cases. This is what makes it unique from if-else where the key word "else" assures that only one set of instructions is chosen. Add a break at the end of each case to prevent this as good practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what you want to print at compile time, you can use the preprocessor like this:

**Code**

```
#define STRINGIFY(word) (#word)

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d %s\n", TEST2, STRINGIFY(TEST2)); 

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

> 1 TEST2

**Big But**

However, this is really no different than doing this:

```
printf("%d TEST2\n", TEST2);
```

Comment: Wow, nice way too. Thx !

Comment: @Laykker It's probably not what you want.  See my update.